# Method calls on android screen rotation

Tags: android

I have an android project in which I had to put a checkbox and a button such that if the checkbox is checked then the button is enabled, otherwise it is not enabled. Firstly I implemented this by setting onClick attribute of the checkbox, but when the checkbox was checked and I rotated the screen the button switched to not enabled although the checkbox is still checked. So I tried to use the setOnCheckedChangeListener method of checkbox and it worked (after screen rotation the button was still enabled). Why does it happen?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: keep in mind that when the rotation happens the activity goes to onPause the OnResume

Comment: On screen rotation, the activity is recreated. If you want to save state, you need to override `onSaveInstance()` of your Activity. Then restore state in `onCreate()`. I heard that if the view (`TextView`, `EditText`, etc) has an ID, its state is automatically saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate the screen, the activity is basically recreated.  Some state information may be automatically preserved, but you should become more familiar with the overall activity lifecycle to understand the subtle differences.

[activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code in your activity inside your manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jerry's answer, to get around the issue quickly, you can simply make boolean member variables in your activity for each of your check boxes. These should then persist through orientation change.

Jerry is right, make sure you know about the Android Lifecycle.